# Что можно закастить в SortedSet?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Никак не могу понять, что еще можно отлить в SortedSet. Перепробовал несколько типов коллекций.
Выдает ошибку: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.SortedOps$OfRef cannot be cast to java.util.SortedSet`.

Само задание:
На вход получаю коллекцию пользователей, удаляю все дубли(имя и возраст), сортируем по имени и возрасту, возвращаем последнего пользователя.

Мое решение:

```java
 public static User task1(Collection<User> source) {
        Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>(source);
        Collection<User> filter = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        SortedSet<User> sortedUser = (SortedSet<User>) filter.stream().sorted();
        return sortedUser.last();
    }
```

TEST:

```java
@Test
    public void task1() {
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User("Ivan", 15), new User("Masha", 17), new User("Kolya", 23), new User("Denis", 7), new User("Vova", 45), new User("Marina", 15), new User("Kolya", 15), new User("Vova", 25), new User("Vlad", 26), new User("Ivan", 17));

        User result = Lesson11to12_SetMap.task1(users);
        Assertions.assertEquals("Vova", result.getName(), "В конце должен быть Vova, 45 лет");
        Assertions.assertEquals(45, result.getAge(), "В конце должен быть Vova, 25 лет");
    }
```

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` - из этого `Set` не получится

Comment: поменял на `toSet()` - разницы никакой, та же ошибка!

Comment: `Assertions.assertEquals(45, result.getAge(), "В конце должен быть Vova, 25 лет");`
Так в конце должен быть 45 или 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Само задание: На вход получаю коллекцию пользователей, удаляю все дубли(имя и возраст), сортируем по имени и возрасту, возвращаем последнего пользователя.

Проще говоря, нужно получить максимальный элемент коллекции

```
public static User task1(Collection<User> users) {
    return Collections.max(users, Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparingInt(User::getAge));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это

```
System.out.println(users.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()) instanceof HashSet);
```

Выводит `true`.
P.S.: В исходниках `toSet()` нет имплементации интерфейса `SortedSet`

Важные интерфейсы, которые реализует HashSet:

> Set, Collection

`SortedSet` же интерфейс. А так как его нет в списке интерфейсов, которые реализует `HashSet`(учитывать P.S.) - значит и привести к нему вы не можете.

Я бы переписал вашу функцию так:

```
public static User task1(Collection<User> source) {
    Object[] users = source.stream().distinct().sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparingInt(User::getAge)).toArray();
    return (User) users[users.length - 1];
}
```

Правда, `distinct`(удаление дубликатов) не нужен, так как нам все равно, сколько дубликатов будет на конце - нам же последний User нужен.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class ru.java.courses.Lesson11to12_SetMap$User cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable`

Comment: @ArturVartanyan так ваш User должен реализовывать интерфейс Comparable.