# После сортировки выводит не тот элемент, который нужен

Tags: java, коллекции, потоки-данных

В дополнении к вопросу [Что можно закастить в SortedSet?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072634/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-sortedset?noredirect=1#comment1841094_1072634), нашел решение, но выдает другую ошибку! Почему, не могу понять...

```java
Collection<User> users = new HashSet<>(source);
        List<User> forReturn = new ArrayList<>(users);
        forReturn.stream().sorted();
        return forReturn.get(users.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Вы ищете максимальный элемент с помощью сортировки? Или это просто пример такой?

Comment: ссылка на предыдущий вопрос. Там сможете увидеть задание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стрим так не работает. это все таки уже функционалка. Мало того, что стрим ленивый, так он еще выводит результат исключительно через терминальные вызовы, посему для вывода в лист он создаст вам новую коллекцию. Выглядит это так:

```
Collection<User> users = new HashSet<>(source);
List<User> forReturn = new ArrayList<>(users);
return forReturn.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).get(users.size() - 1);
```

Однако, вы должны понимать, что это очень плохая идея. Вы ищите 1 элемент по определенному признаку, для этого сортировать нерационально, ибо ресурсозатратно. Мало того, если вы не имплеиментируете Comparable либо не напищите Comparator для класса User, то получите ошибку во всех случаях сортировки (именно поэтому вы получааете класскаст для сортированной коллекции).

Если вы хотите использовать стрим, то лучше сделать так

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private final String name;
    private final Integer age;

    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<User> list = Arrays.asList(new User("Igor", 25), new User("Masha", 32), new User("Dasha", 22));
        User user = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge, Comparator.reverseOrder())).get();
        System.out.println(user);
    }

}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку кастинга, к сожалению

Comment: @ Artur Vartanyan к сожалению , экстрасенсов тут нет. вы принимаете какой -то source в коллекцию, вы не показали ваш класс юзера. я понятия не имею что и где вы кастите т как и что вы сортируете. код , который я вам отдал, работает. я даже специально для вас создал в юзере метод мейн и скопировал все туда, чтобы можно было просто запустить и проверить. а если хотитите отдебажить свой код, то выложите все для того, чтобы это можно было воспроизвести

Comment: Дмитрий, излишнее проявление агрессии. Я оценил Ваш ответ. Не злитесь, я еще даже не джун, поэтому заранее извините, если вдруг, что-то не так

Comment: Кстати, класс Вы описали очень верно, у меня так же

Comment: @ Artur Vartanyan здесь оценивать ответ не обязательно. просто в том виде, в котором вы показываете код , есть два варианта: предложить свое решение,  либо угадывать, что написано в других ваших классах. первое я уже сделал и перепроверил, второе невозможно в принципе, поэтому было предложено выложить код. соответственно, это предложено, чтобы помочь разобраться. посему нет здесь  никакой агрессии. хотя агрессивная помощь звучит забавно))

Comment: стримы странная штука)

Comment: @Artur Vartanyan другая парадигма... если правильно использовать, то очень эффективная. не забывайте, что стримы все умеют паралелить из коробки, а это задача далеко нетривиальная

Comment: полностью согласен)